# PHP manipulate Excel XLSX with COM, fail to add a file to OleObjects

Tags: php, excel

i'm doing Excel XLSX editing with PHP through COM component,

i need to add an outside txt file to a sheet as an OleObjects,

here is my code:

```
$tmpSheet = $excel->ActiveWorkbook->Sheets->Add();
$tmpSheet->Activate();
$tmpSheet->Name = "runLog";

$tmpObj = array("", "e:/test01.txt"
                =);
$tmpSheet->OLEObjects->Add($tmpObj);
```

return error is:

Source:</b> Microsoft ExcelDescription:</b> Cannot insert object.

how can i solve it?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved myself........

final code:

```
        $tmpSheet = $excel->ActiveWorkbook->Sheets->Add(null, $tmpSheet);
        $tmpSheet->Activate();
        $tmpSheet->Name = $resultSheetName;

        $tmpSheet = $excel->ActiveWorkbook->Sheets($excel->ActiveWorkbook->Sheets->Count);
        $tmpSheet->OLEObjects->Add(null, "" . __dir__ . "/" . $tmpSrcFilePath);
```

notice:

i. first param ClassType set to null.

ii. second param FileName set to full path.

thank you everyone.........